# Send POST data via raw JSON with Postman

Tags: php, json, rest, postman

I've got Postman (the one that doesn't open in Chrome) and I'm trying to do a POST request using raw JSON.

In the Body tab I have "raw" selected and "JSON (application/json)" with this body:

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

For the header I have 1, `Content-Type: application/json`

On the PHP side I'm just doing `print_r($_POST);` for now, and I'm getting an empty array.

---

If I use jQuery and do:

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "POST",
    "url": "/rest/index.php",
    "data": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}).done(function (d) {
    console.log(d);
});
```

I'm getting as expected:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```

So why isn't it working with Postman?

---

Postman screenshots:

[image]

and header:

[image]

Comment: Try $_REQUEST instead $_POST and var_dump() instead print_r()

Comment: @Deep I get `array(1) {["foo"]=>  string(3) "bar"}` with jQuery and still an empty array with Postman: `array(0) {}`

Comment: So Postman not sending request

Comment: @smerny in your post `fields` and `foo` wont match thus it won't work, Im not sure if it is a typo but make sure they match

Comment: @meda, right that was a typo, but if I had fields it still should have output in the var dump of $_REQUEST or $_POST

Comment: @smerny so how can we troubleshoot it, you got screenshot

Comment: @meda - screenshot posted

Comment: @smerny try `print_r(file_get_contents("php://input"));` because you are sending raw json.  `print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true));`

Comment: @meda, interesting... this is giving me `{ "foo": "bar"}` with Postman now... and `foo=bar` with jQuery. I really need it to give me the same thing in both places... Postman is really just for testing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121215/discussion-between-meda-and-smerny).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Unlike `jQuery` in order to read raw `JSON` you will need to decode it in PHP.

```
print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true));
```

`php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body.

`$_POST` is form variables, you will need to switch to `form` radiobutton in `postman` then use:

```
foo=bar&foo2=bar2
```

To post raw `json` with `jquery`:

```
$.ajax({
    "url": "/rest/index.php",
    'data': JSON.stringify({foo:'bar'}),
    'type': 'POST',
    'contentType': 'application/json'
});
```

Comment: yes exaclty posting json vs post variables are different

Answer (score 95):

Just check JSON option from the drop down next to binary; when you click raw. This should do

[image: skill synon pass json to postman]

Comment: this is a fairly old post.. but if you look at the question you'll see that I did exactly that.  you may want to read the question, the selected answer, and the comments on the selected answer to understand the problem and solution better.

Comment: Sure, but this actually pinpointed the issue I had; I had "Text" selected, not application/json, even though that was already mentioned in the Headers section. Its confusing; if you choose "Text", then the entire HTTP POST "code" is displayed, including the JSON, which I expected to work, since its a full POST call, not just the json.

Comment: Great! this was my "issue". I've expected that the JSON is a logical default

Answer (score 9):

meda's answer is completely legit, but when I copied the code I got an error!

Somewhere in the `"php://input"` there's an invalid character (maybe one of the quotes?).

When I typed the `"php://input"` code manually, it worked.
Took me a while to figure out!

Comment: Glad I scrolled down a little further and saw this - I was having the same issue. Good find!

Comment: It looks like someone fixed it in an edit to meda's post. But I looked at the edit history and found that the original post had `200c 200b` (zero width characters) between the "n" and "p" in "input". Not sure how he ended up with that, but it's fixed now.

Comment: Glad I scrolled down. after around 3 hours of wastage got it fixed

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same problem, following code worked for me:

```
$params = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
print_r($params);
```

---

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1**
[image: You can send using form-data]

**Solution 2**
[image: You can send using raw json data]

Both solutions are working perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: Only the second option worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Install Postman native app, Chrome extension has been deprecated.
(Mine was opening in own window but still ran as Chrome app)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @jhpratt actually it does. I had same problem. When used Postman app, it worked. Question is: So why isn't it working with Postman?