# Retrieving json submitted by postman in php

Tags: php, api, postman

I'm creating an api using php and I'm using postman to test my requests.

in postman I choose the method of posting and in body use the raw to send a json to my api

```
category{
    "id":"1",
    "desc": "testing",
    "observation": "testing",
}
```

it sends perfectly, but how can I recover my json on the server side? in my php

i'm using

```
$result = json_decode($_POST['category'], true);
```

but the error occurs

```
 Notice: Undefined index: category in
```

[image: Postman]

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST);` in your code.

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Look how my postman is, I've edited my question.

Comment: sorry the print was without the category in postman, but even with it it does not work

Comment: var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));

Comment: have you tried this one `$inputData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);`

Comment: You did not send post data (urlencoded), you did not send valid json either.

Comment: var_dump (file_get_contents ('php: // input')); this returns me but everything as a string, as it is possible to return the json object

Comment: @EmiryMirella check out this question + answer which is identical to your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008071/send-post-data-via-raw-json-with-postman

Comment: Look up [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in the manual. Thats how you convert a JSON String to a PHP Object or Array

Comment: But would not he return me json without me having to convert? or is it not possible

Comment: ___The point of JSON___ is to be able to move a data structure from anywhere to anywhere. Therefore the data is passed around as a String ALWAYS. Then each language has a mechanism to convert it to a language specific datatype which is  `json_decode()` in PHP

Comment: in my case, I needed extra "/" at the end of url, for example I was using "localhost/test" but "localhost/test/" was needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the data is in the actual body you might need to retrieve it instead of looking in the $_POST array:

**Try this:**

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $body;
```

As seen in the comments of the question, you can use `json_decode()` to get a php object.

```
$object = json_decode($body);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($object);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: But is it not possible for me to receive the json object without having to do this? look for it?

Comment: JSON is just a string, not an object. You need to decode it in order to use it and manipulate it easier.

Comment: @Jeppsen In ALL cases JSON is passed about as a string! Just like XML is also passed as a string

Comment: now that I have the json object it's not just me to use echo $ object->descricao; to retrieve each separate element?

Comment: If the json string is valid and the json_decode returns a stdClass object you should indeed be able to access each element with "->"

Comment: $params = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
echo json_encode($params);