# How to send nested values in postman

Tags: php, rest, api

i have a conflict in some point , i need to receive this representation after consuming my endpoint .

the response is like that  :

```
{"6451":{"option":1,"note":""},"6460":{"option":1,"note":""}}
```

How can i send the above format but in the correct way please  through postman application , i don't have an imagination for forming the parameters which i will receive in my PHP controller

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008071/send-post-data-via-raw-json-with-postman

Comment: actually am working on a framework where i should pass the data in particular shape like this  params[divid] , params[courseid] , etc ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST data via raw json with postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008071/send-post-data-via-raw-json-with-postman)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the raw format in your body request, set application/json and paste your json:

```
{
  "6451": {
    "option": 1,
    "note": ""
  },
  "6460": {
    "option": 1,
    "note": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Is what am doing is correct , see the following picture : https://serving.photos.photobox.com/110099627d0a7ef0d2495b7c98518579b9167cfd10b0b0f3f7b167ab6a43c7c66801c72e.jpg . cause am stick with a structure to follow for sending parameters

Comment: Check this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e48hy9vu85w5mv3/Screenshot%202018-12-13%2014.05.18.png?dl=0