# Unable to receieve the body object from the react frontend to backend(express) api, while it works fine when submit using postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

Below is my frontend code i have to submit a post request from react.

```js
const { name, email, message } = greeting;
const payload = {
  name: name,
  email: email,
  message: message,
};

console.log(payload);

fetch('http://localhost:8080/greetings', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },

  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
})
  .then(async function (res) {
    let response = await res.json();
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Below is my express code for post

```js
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/greetings', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  db();
  const saveDocument = new Document({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    message: message,
  });

  await saveDocument
    .save()
    .then((savedDoc) => {
      res.send({ status: 200, mes: 'success', request: req.body });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
});
```

I have tried to submit a post using postman and i was able to see data in my mongoDB. But from my frontend i always get an empty object in the request.body.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 different types of commonly used `Content-Type`:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `application/json`

In Postman, you have specified to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`, which is why there's a mismatch between the behaviour in Postman and `fetch` request in React.

When you specified your request to use `application/json`, your Express server needs to be able to handle the parsing as well.

In Express 4.16 and above, you can use the `express.json()` middleware to parse your request into a JSON object to be retrieved using `req.body`, `bodyParser` (or `body-parser`) is deprecated. An example is as follows:

```js
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/greetings', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  db();
  const saveDocument = new Document({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    message: message,
  });

  await saveDocument
    .save()
    .then((savedDoc) => {
      res.send({ status: 200, mes: 'success', request: req.body });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
});
```

The [`express.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) is a middleware to parse `Content-Type: application/json`, whereas [`express.urlencoded()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) is used to parse `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

---

In order to test sending `Content-Type: application/json` in Postman, you can follow the screenshot below:

[image: Postman Headers]

[image: Postman Body]

(Screenshot source: [Send POST data via raw JSON with Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008071/send-post-data-via-raw-json-with-postman))

Comment: @NomulaLenin feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the check button next to it whenever you think this is the best answer you would get.